# Promise scope different at execution time

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, sequelize.js

I'm trying to wait (`Promise.all`) on an array of **Promises** that run database queries using **Sequelize.js**, which **resolves** from a `then`.

I'm pushing my promises as follows:

```js
for (furnix in shorthandFurni) {

    furniData = shorthandFurni[furnix]
    furniSplit = furniData.split(":")    

    CompletedPromises.push(new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
        db.query("...").then(result => {
            . . .

            // depending on the for-loop
            resolve({
              otherdbdata: . . .,
              furniData: furniData,
              furniSplit: furniSplit
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Then returning (after the for loop).

```
return Promise.all(CompletionPromises)
```

That's all great and all, but the problem stems from the variables `furniData` and `furniSplit` being part of the resolution to my promises... Right now, when this code is executed on my server it returns the variable `furniSplit` the same for all of the promise resolutions.

#### Basically, I'm wondering how I can bring **`furniSplit`** as a variable, into the scope of the resolve function so that on each iteration of the for loop it gives unique data, instead of the last.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: don't use global variable ... use `let furniData =` and `let furniSplit =` and all will be well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, this seems to be a scoping issue.
Try

```
const furniSplit = furniData.split(":");
```

Comment: I added some more to my question now, I tried your solution and I had the same result as before.

Comment: @JackHales Did you put `const` for both `furniData` and `furniSplit`?

Comment: Oh! Working now! To be fair I'm not really sure why making it a constant would make it work, in my eyes, it was a scope that was being dynamically accessed AFTER the variable was set. Can you explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: It's called [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) and results in variables being added to the scope outside the function and being overwritten

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function to get the new same value Data, but they are not equal, bacause the reference is different.

```
   for (furnix in shorthandFurni) {

    const furniData = () => shorthandFurni[furnix]
    const furniSplit = () => furniData.split(":")    

    CompletedPromises.push(new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
        db.query("...").then(result => {
            . . .

            // depending on the for-loop
            resolve({
              otherdbdata: . . .,
              furniData: furniData(),
              furniSplit: furniSplit()
            })
        })
    })
}
```